# How can I append ContextPath automatically in URL?

Tags: javascript, spring, jsp

I want to know how to automatically append `{pageContext.request.contextPath}` on URL when I send URL to controller. 
I have always added it when I set all urlPath( location.href, img src,a href and so on). So How should I do if I always don't want to add it on urlPath?

Comment: use jstl <c:url> or <spring:url> tags

Comment: Thank you so much. the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jstl like below:

```
<%@ taglib uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix = "c" %>

<html>
   <head>
      <title><c:url> Tag Example</title>
   </head>

   <body>
      <a href = "<c:url value = "/jsp/index.htm"/>">TEST</a>
   </body>
</html>
```